# 1を255、2を254と表示していると思われるソフトウェアがあるのですが、どういう法則ですか？

Tags: windows-10

Windowsのとあるソフトウェアで、1と思われる値を255、2と思われる値を254と表示しているのですが、
仮にそうだとしたら、どういう法則性が考えられますか？
何かの進数変換ですか？

---

経緯
新品のカメラをネットで購入しました。
本当に新品であるかどうか確認したかったので、シャッター回数を調べることにしました。
ネットに掲載されている情報を 4 つ試してみたのですが、いずれも一致しませんでした。
その内の 2 つは、画像をアップロードして判定するタイプだったので算出根拠は分かりません。
残る 2 つのインストールするタイプの内、XnViewは、総レリーズ回数が表示されませんでした。
最後の 1 つである「XnView MP」のExifTool欄に「Shot Number Since Power Up」という項目があり、これがシャッター回数かもしれない、と思いました。
画像3枚撮影して、ExifTool項目を確認したら、それぞれ「0」「255」「254」でした。
「255」「254」の意味がそれぞれ「1」「2」だったら、この項目がシャッター回数だと思い質問しました。

Comment: 「とある」とかボカした表現ではなくキチンと特定できるソフトウェア名称と、どういう状態・状況でのどの部分の表示なのかを記述した方が良いでしょう。何か守秘義務に関わるとかならば、こういう場所でボカした表現での質問も避けた方が良いと思われますが。

Comment: そのソフトウェアの開発元に聞くべきでしょう。

Comment: ソフトウェアは「XnView MP」で、表示欄は「Shot Number Since Power Up」です。シャッター回数を確認しようと思ったのですが、よく分からなかったので質問しました。

Comment: これでしょうか。[XnView MP: Image management](https://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/), [XnViewMP for Windows のインストールと使い方](https://eizone.info/xnviewmp-for-windows/), [XnView MP 1.4.3](https://softaro.net/xnview-mp/) 何に対してどのような使い方をした場合に何処に表示されている情報なのかを提示してみてください。

Comment: Exifのメタデータですよね。データを見るソフトウェアの話ではなくて、そのデータを書き込んだ"もの"が何なのか? が大事な話かと思います。 参考 https://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/60600101

Comment: 経緯を本文に追記しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

その数値の意味は正直私には予測付きませんが数字自体の法則としてはunsigned char型(0-255)を減算表記しているのではないかと思われます。

(追記)
XnViewの場合は[Exif]->総レリーズ回数でシャッター数を確認できるようです。

XnView MPも同じかどうか不明ですが確認してみるのも一考かと
https://akistyle.jp/xnview-shutter

Comment: XnViewもインストールしてみたのですが、総レリーズ回数は表示されませんでした

Comment: 提示したサイトによるとプロパティではなくブラウザ下部のExifタブを開くとありますがそちらに記載されていなかったということでしょうか？

Comment: はい。「総レリーズ回数」という項目自体が表示されませんでした…